# Magento 2 An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again

Tags: checkout, sales-order, magento-2.0

I know my question are like [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149546/magento-2-an-error-occurred-on-the-server-please-try-to-place-the-order-again)

But in my case when I check errors I see this

> Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Interceptor::_getResource","trace":"#0 /backup/html/toph/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(151, Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment), Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))\n#1 /backup/html/toph/var/generation/Magento/Checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement/Interceptor.php(26):

I remove **`var/generation`** and **`re compile`** my code and set permission to file but error does not fixed .

Comment: What is happening after the error ? Still the quote persist or cart is getting empty ?

Comment: @KalyanChakravarthiV no just show error and stay on checkout
error occur when i click place order

Comment: Please attach complete stack trace

Comment: @KalyanChakravarthiV it is here https://paste.ubuntu.ir/kegr

Comment: Thanks, did you try different payment methods ?

Comment: @KalyanChakravarthiV yes ... i have 3 payment method and test with all

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to display the real error by editing the model files based on the error ajax call

Edit the function **savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder** in

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php

or for Guest orders in

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php

Change the function from:

```
public function savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
    $cartId,
    $email,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
) {
    $this->savePaymentInformation($cartId, $email, $paymentMethod, $billingAddress);
    try {
        $orderId = $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($cartId);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(
            __('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.'),
            $e
        );
    }
    return $orderId;
}
```

to:

```
public function savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
    $cartId,
    $email,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
) {
    $this->savePaymentInformation($cartId, $email, $paymentMethod, $billingAddress);
    try {
        $orderId = $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($cartId);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(
            __($e->getMessage()),
            $e
        );
    }
    return $orderId;
}
```

Now you get the actual error and you should find the full exception in the exception.log file

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

That was because of some observer have error ..
after disable `observer` order was placed 
best way for check error is change

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php

line 70 to

```
 catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(
            __('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.'.$e->getMessage()),
            $e
        );
    }
```

and also check the console log