# Order not placed in magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, sales-order, exception

Not able to place the order in magento2 checkout.

getting below error when place order button is clicked.

```
  An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.
```

The request to rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information

is showing 400 Bad request.

Can anyone help me with this issue please.
Thanks

Comment: Which payment method are you using ?

Comment: its not working for any of the payment methods, i am using sagepay and pay by cheque.

Comment: Have you checked my posted answer link.

Comment: Do you have any cart rules applied?

Comment: Yes, using some cart price rules but all they are inactive

Comment: Please check the var/log/system.log, var/log/exception.log file to check the issue

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this link for a solution to debug your cause:**

[Magento 2: An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149546/magento-2-an-error-occurred-on-the-server-please-try-to-place-the-order-again)

Hope it help!