# The shipping address is missing. Set the address and try again

Tags: onepage-checkout, payment-methods, magento2.4.6

I am getting an error like `The shipping address is missing. Set the address and try again in magento2 checkout page.`

Log with `\n`s replaced with line breaks for readability.

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php(206): Magento\\Quote\\Model\\PaymentMethodManagement->set()
#1 /var/www/html/artisandev/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\PaymentInformationManagement->savePaymentInformation()
#2 /var/www/html/artisandev/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Checkout\\Model\\PaymentInformationManagement\\Interceptor->__callParent()
#3 /var/w…code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->__callPlugins()
#12 vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\\Webapi\\Controller\\Rest\\Interceptor->dispatch()
#13 /var/www/html/artisandev/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()
#14 pub/index.php(30): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run()
#15 {main}"
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to be same problem like 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149546/magento-2-an-error-occurred-on-the-server-please-try-to-place-the-order-again

Please review and let me know if it works

Comment: I couldn't reproduce issue on magento instance either.
After I adding $customerId = $this->customerSession->getId(); in to begging of the function private function doValidate(AddressInterface $address, ?int $customerId): void in the file magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteAddressValidator.php the error stop showing up. And I could pass to payment page. How is possible customerId passing as null? it happens when I logged in and trying place order with saved address.

copied from https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23908

Comment: @SunilSharma That's quote formatting, not code. Code formatting is done with triple backticks. There was no reason to include the image in the quotes either.